# can I make a express comparision on j with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Say I have 2 data.table sets,

```
DT1 <- data.table(x=1L, y=2L, z=3L)
DT2 <- data.table(x=1:3L, y=2:4L, z=3:5L)

B <- DT2[x==1 & y == 2 & z == 3]
identical(DT1, B)  # TRUE
```

can I do something like `DT2[c(x,y,z) == DT1]` and get the result?
Assume it shall be more graceful than `DT2[x==1 & y == 2 & z == 3]` when there are lot of condition to compare with. Please advise.

Thanks to Akrun & Michael.
What I am looking for is a expression of comparison in j. another toy example is here.

```
minDT <- data.table(x=1L, y=1L, z=1L) # side-finding:
maxDT <- data.table(x=3L, y=3L, z=3L) # i noticed it would be numeric if not L
aimDT <- data.table(x=1:3, y=1:3, z=1:3) # in this case, the value is integer
```

I am trying if I can do the comparison all at once, not have to do 
`aimDT[x>1 & x<3 & y>1 & y<3 & z>1 & z<3]` but something like 
`aimDT[c(x,y,z)> minDT][c(x,y,z)<maxDT]`

Thanks.

Comment: I have a feeling your example is too simple to capture what you're after. Could you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: For now, see: https://jangorecki.gitlab.io/data.table/library/data.table/html/setops.html

Comment: Thanks, Michael, just let me figure out how I can express myself clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to compare the corresponding columns of 'DT2' and 'DT2', do it with `Map` and `Reduce` it to a logical `vector` with `&` for subsetting the rows of 'DT2'

```
DT2[DT2[, Reduce(`&`, Map(`==`, .SD, DT1))]]
#    x y z
#1:  1 2 3
```

---

Or set the keys with `setkey` and use the 'DT1' values for subsetting rows

```
setkeyv(DT2, names(DT2))
DT2[DT1]

# or unkeyed, safer against columns being out of order
DT2[DT1, on=names(DT1)]
```

Comment: Thank, @Akrun, let me figure out how it works. Thanks.

Comment: Follow up question, what if I need `DT[x > 1 & y >2 & z >3]`? let's not consider different direction issues.

Comment: @Grec001  Try with a non-equi join `DT2[DT1, .(x, y, z), on = .(x > x, y > y, z > z)]` or use `DT2[DT2[, Reduce('&', Map('>', .SD, DT1))]]`

Comment: @Grec001 The first one should be `DT2[DT1, indx := 1, on = .(x > x, y > y, z > z)];DT2[!is.na(indx)]`